# Restore XP mode

Tags: windows-7, system-restore, windows-xp-mode

I started getting an error going into XP Mode. My host OS is Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.

> Could not enable integration features.

I uninstalled and then reinstalled XP Mode, and I can get in now, but forgot I had some important files on the old XP Mode desktop.

When I go to "Previous Versions" in Explorer, I do see copies of what I think are the xp mode files at dates prior to me getting the error.

**What files do I need to restore to get my "XP Mode" back to a certain point?**

I'm assuming that I need

- all files in the `user\me\appdata\local\microsoft\windows virtual PC\virtual machines\*.*`
- The .vhd file in c:\program files\windows xp mode

Is this correct? Any other files?
Do I just need to exit out of XP Mode completely, restore these files, and then start up XP Mode again?

**Please note:**

I do realize that I may be back to where I get the "could not enable integration features error", but I've since learned that I
may be able to fix this another way.

Comment: Just to be sure, What is the OS your are running XP mode in?

Comment: Windows 7 Professional 64bit

Answer (score 3):

The files are stored in the XP VHD image, when you reinstalled it deleted this image and your data.

If you can use Windows System Restore to somehow restore the old VHD file, then you are in business.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That is what I would have thought as well.  However, if this is the case, why, when I go to "previous versions" in Explorer am I seeing .vhd's  in the virtual machine folder that predate the reinstall?

Comment: If you right click on the VHD and select properties, then go to the Previous Versions tab, it will list all previous version available and the dates of the previous files. The date you need would be before the reinstall date. You never answered my comment below your post about the OS.

Comment: Not sure how you are accessing previous versions in Explorer. Its possible the reinstall of xp mode left the old vhds. I would need a screenshot to venture a guess as to what you are seeing.

Comment: I think you need previous versions of all the files in the user account folder, the one in program folder is the base image that is not used.